# Why is TIC-80 giving me the attempt to index a nil value error?

Tags: class, object, oop, lua

So I am building a game for a game jam over at itch.io, and I'm using this really neat Fantasy Console called TIC-80, found at tic80.com. My issue is that while I understand what the error message is and what it means, I don't understand as to why it's giving me this error.

Error Message (In the TIC-80 console):

```
>[string "-- title:  The Clone 
Wars..."]:144: attempt to index a nil 
value (field '?')
stack traceback:
    [string "-- title:  The Clone 
Wars..."]:144: in function 'TIC'
```

The Code in question:

```
-- title:  The Clone Wars
-- author: DinoNuggies
-- desc:   Help the jedi destroy the clones!
-- script: lua

--Functions
function sign(n) return n>0 and 1 or n<0 and -1 or 0 end
function lerp(a,b,t) return (1-t)*a + t*b end
function tablelength(T)
  local count = 0
  for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
  return count
end
--End of Functions


--Variables
player = {
    spr = 256,
    sprMod = 0,
    x = 1,
    y = 1,
    vx = 0,
    vy = 0,
    dirX = 0,
    dirY = 0,
    flip = 0,
    shoot = false,
}
gun = {
    t = 0,
    spr = 258,
    sprMod = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    modX = 0,
    modY = 0,
    flip = 0,
    rot = 0,
}
tile = {
    r0 = 0,
    r1 = 0,
    l0 = 0,
    l1 = 0,
    u0 = 0,
    u1 = 0,
    d0 = 0,
    d1 = 0,
    m = 0,
}
m = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    left = false,
    right = false,
    middle = false,
}
cam = {
    activate = true,
    x = 120,
    y = 64,
}

    --Bullet Class & Functions
bulletMod = 0
bullet = {}
function bullet:new()
    local this = {
        spr = 260,
        x = player.x,
        y = player.y,
        vx = 0,
        vy = 0,
        mx = m.x - (player.x + cam.x),
        my = m.y - (player.y + cam.y),
        t = 0,
    }
    return this
end

function bullet:remove()
    local this = {
        spr = nil,
        x = nil,
        y = nil,
        vx = nil,
        vy = nil,
        mx = nil,
        my = nil,
        t = nil,
    }
    return this
end
--End of Variables

function TIC()
    cls()

    --Camera
    if cam.activate then
        cam.x = math.min(120, lerp(cam.x, 120-player.x, 0.05))
        cam.y = math.min(64, lerp(cam.y, 64-player.y, 0.05))
        ccx = cam.x / 8 + (cam.x % 8 == 0 and 1 or 0)
        ccy = cam.y / 8 + (cam.y % 8 == 0 and 1 or 0)
    end
    map(15 - ccx, 8 - ccy, 31, 18, (cam.x % 8) - 8, (cam.y % 8) - 8, 0)
    --End of Camera


    --Gun Physics
    m.x, m.y, m.left, m.middle, m.right = mouse()
    gun.x = player.x + cam.x
    gun.y = player.y + cam.y
    bullets = tablelength(bullet) - 2
    flick = (time() // 16) % 16 == 0
    if m.left then m.leftp = flick else m.leftp = false end

        --Gun Display
    if m.x > player.x + cam.x + 4 then
        gun.flip = 0
        gun.modX = 4
    else
        gun.flip = 1
        gun.modX = -4
    end

        --Gun Firing
    if m.leftp == true then
        bullet[bullets] = bullet:new()
        if m.x > player.x + cam.x + 4 then
            bullet[bullets].vx = 8
        else
            bullet[bullets].vx = -8
        end
    end
    --End of Gun Physics


    --Bullet Physics
    if bullets > 0 then
        for i=0,bullets-1 do

            bullet[i].x = bullet[i].x + bullet[i].vx --LINE 144, THE ONE IN QUESTION
            bullet[i].y = bullet[i].y + bullet[i].vy

            spr(bullet[i].spr, bullet[i].x + cam.x, bullet[i].y + cam.y, 0, 1)

            bullet[i].t = bullet[i].t + 1
            if bullet[i].t > 16 then
                bullet[i] = bullet:remove()
                bullet[i] = nil
            end
        end
    end
    bullets = tablelength(bullet) - 2
    --End of Bullet Physics


    --Drawing
        --Sprites
    spr(player.spr + player.sprMod, player.x + cam.x, player.y + cam.y, 0, 1, player.flip)
    spr(gun.spr + gun.sprMod, gun.x + gun.modX, gun.y + gun.modY, 0, 1, gun.flip, gun.rot)

        --Debug
    print("Debug:", 1, 1, 11)
    print("X: " .. (player.x // 8) + 15 .. " Y: " .. (player.y // 8) + 9, 1, 8, 11)
    print("BLTs: " .. bullets .. " ", 1, 16, 11)
    --End of Drawing


    --Player Movement
    player.x = player.x + player.vx
    player.y = player.y + player.vy
    if key(1) and player.x > -120 then
        player.vx = -1
        player.sprMod = 1
        player.dirX = 0
    elseif key(4) then 
        player.vx = 1
        player.sprMod = 0
        player.dirX = 1
    else
        player.vx = 0
    end
    if key(23) and player.y > -64 then
        player.vy = -1
        player.dirY = 0
    elseif key(19) then
        player.vy = 1
        player.dirY = 1
    else
        player.vy = 0
    end

    if btnp(0) then player.y = player.y - 1
    elseif btnp(1) then player.y = player.y + 1
    elseif btnp(2) then player.x = player.x - 1
    elseif btnp(3) then player.x = player.x + 1
    end
    --End of Movement


    --Player Collision
    tile.r0 = mget(((player.x + 7) // 8) + 15, ((player.y - 9) // 8) + 9)
    tile.r1 = mget(((player.x + 7) // 8) + 15, ((player.y - 2) // 8) + 9)
    tile.l0 = mget(((player.x - 2) // 8) + 15, ((player.y - 9) // 8) + 9)
    tile.l1 = mget(((player.x - 2) // 8) + 15, ((player.y - 2) // 8) + 9)
    tile.u0 = mget(((player.x - 1) // 8) + 15, ((player.y - 10) // 8) + 9)
    tile.u1 = mget(((player.x + 6) // 8) + 15, ((player.y - 10) // 8) + 9)
    tile.d0 = mget(((player.x - 1) // 8) + 15, ((player.y - 1) // 8) + 9)
    tile.d1 = mget(((player.x + 6) // 8) + 15, ((player.y - 1) // 8) + 9)

    if player.dirX == 1 then
        if fget(tile.r0, 0) or fget(tile.r1, 0) then
            player.vx = 0
        end
    elseif player.dirX == 0 then
        if fget(tile.l0, 0) or fget(tile.l1, 0) then
            player.vx = 0
        end
    end

    if player.dirY == 0 then
        if fget(tile.u0, 0) or fget(tile.u1, 0) then
            player.vy = 0
        end
    elseif player.dirY == 1 then
        if fget(tile.d0, 0) or fget(tile.d1, 0) then
            player.vy = 0
        end
    end
    --End of Player Collision


    --Misc
    if keyp(3) then
        if cam.activate then
            cam.activate = false
        else
            cam.activate = true
        end
    end
    --End of Misc
end

--DON'T WORRY ABOUT ANYTHING PAST THIS POINT, IT'S ONLY SPRITE AND TILE DEFINITIONS FOR TIC-80 VISUALS

-- <TILES>
-- 000:6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666
-- 001:6666666666566566666666656666666665665666666665666566666666666666
-- 002:6668666666898566666866656666666665665866686689868986686668666666
-- 003:6656556666555556555556555555556555555555665555556556555666655566
-- 016:dddddddeddddddefddeeeeffddeeeeffddeeeeffddeeeeffdeffffffefffffff
-- 017:6226622661266126222222221121112161266126612661265126512665266525
-- 018:6228622661298126222222221121112161266126612681268126512668266525
-- 019:6226522661255126222222221121112151255125612551255126512665255525
-- </TILES>

-- <SPRITES>
-- 000:00cccc000cccccd00cbbbbb0ccbbcbbdcccfefcd0dddddd000ceec0000c00c00
-- 001:00cccc000cccccd00bbbbbd0cbbcbbcdccfefccd0dddddd000ceec0000c00c00
-- 002:000000000000000000000000000eeeed000efff0000ef0000000000000000000
-- 003:0000ed00000eef0000eef0000eef000000eef000000ee0000000000000000000
-- 004:0000000000000000000000000aaaaaa00aaaaaa0000000000000000000000000
-- </SPRITES>

-- <MAP>
-- 000:010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010000000000000000000000101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 001:010000000000000000000000000000101000101000001000000010101001010000000000100000000000101010000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 002:010001000100010000000000000010000000100010001000100010001001010000000010100000000000101010000000000000001010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 003:010001000100000000000000000000101000100010001000100010100001010000000010000000000000101000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 004:010001010100010000000000000000001000100010001000100010000001010000000010000000000000101010000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 005:010001000100010000000000000010100000001010000010100010000001010000000010000000000000101010000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 006:010000000000000000000000000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 007:010000000000000000000000000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 008:010000000000000000000000000101301010000000000000000000000000000000000000101010000000101000000000000000000010101000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 009:010000000000000000000000000101101010100000000000000000000000000000001010101000000000101000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 010:010000000000000000000000000101101010000000000001111101000000001111111121211111110000101000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 011:010000000000000000000000000101000000000000001000000001000000000000001020101000000000101000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 012:010000000000000000000000000101000000000000011111111101010001010000101010000000000010101000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 013:010000000000000000000000000101000000000010101000000001011101010000101000000000000010100000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 014:010000000000000000000000000101000000000010101010000000000000010000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 015:010000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 016:010101010101010101010101010101000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000001010000000000000001010000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 017:010101010101010101010101010101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101010000000000010102000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- 018:000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000010100000000000000000000000101000000000001010000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 019:000000000000000000001010000101000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000010101000001111211110000000001010000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 020:000000001000000000001000000101000000000000000000000000101000000000000000001010101000000010101011111100000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 021:000000000000000000001010100101101010000000000000000000000000000000000000101000000000001010200000000011110000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 022:000000000000000000000000000101001010100000000000000000000000000000000010101000000010101010100000000000001111000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 023:000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000001010100000000010101010000000000000000000110000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 024:000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000001010100000001020201000000000000000100000001100102001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 025:000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000101010000000001020100000000000000000100000000011212101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 026:000000101000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000001010100010000000001010100000000010000000100010100010101001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 027:000000101010000000000000100101000000000000000010101010101010101010000010000000001010000000000000101010000000001010000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 028:000000100010000000000000100101000000000000000000000000001010101000101010000000001010000010101010000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 029:000000001010000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000010100000000000000000001010000000000000000000100010000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 030:000000001010000000000000000101100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000001000000000100000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 031:000000001010000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 032:000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 033:000000000000000000000000000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- 135:010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
-- </MAP>

-- <WAVES>
-- 000:00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff
-- 001:0123456789abcdeffedcba9876543210
-- 002:0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef
-- </WAVES>

-- <SFX>
-- 000:020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200304000000000
-- 001:020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200307000000000
-- 002:02000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020002000200020030b000000000
-- </SFX>

-- <FLAGS>
-- 000:00000000000000000000000000000000101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-- </FLAGS>

-- <PALETTE>
-- 000:1a1c2c5d2810814428ca9581ffcd7575ae442495482571793c55c22c9dfae20000000000f4f4f494b0c2566c86333c57
-- </PALETTE>
```

What triggers the error, is after the player fires the second bullet. After firing one, the bullet is created, displayed, and despawned on queue, but after the second bullet starts existing, it stops and gives me the error. I've switched things around quite a bit, and it seems like every time I reference to one of the bullet objects values when more then one exists, it sends me the error, which is what I don't understand, as i thought I had already solved that problem with the `for` loops.

So if you noticed anything right off the bat that doesn't look quite right, let me know, and if you don't know anything about TIC-80 or what the API does, I'm sure the TIC-80 website can explain it way better then me.

If you want to run the game, to see the issue in action and mess around with the code, download TIC-80 from the website and run this file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ti0NboNNN9Yog6l_n73usF_eX_86EN4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Some `bullet[i]` is `nil` at line #144.  You may fix it by inserting a code to "compress" the `bullet` array (move nils to the end) before line #156

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at your bullet handling

First call to `TIC`:

`bullets` is 0. We add one bullet into `bullet[0]`

Second call:

`bullets` is 1. We add one bullet into `bullet[1]`.
Now, as `bullets > 0` we enter the bullet physics if statement.

We do some calculations to that bullet and increment `bullet[0].t`

The following calls we do the same. We add a bullet and process all but the new bullet as we did above.
When a bullet's `t` field becomes `> 16` we remove it from `bullet`.

So first we remove the oldest bullet `bullet[0]`. But in the following call we again start our loop at `i = 0`. so `bullet[i]` is `nil` and hence indexing it in `bullet[i].x` causes the observed error.

Side note:

This makes no sense.

```
function bullet:remove()
    local this = {
        spr = nil,
        x = nil,
        y = nil,
        vx = nil,
        vy = nil,
        mx = nil,
        my = nil,
        t = nil,
    }
    return this
end
```

A table with all nil values is just an empty table. So simply return an empty table.

On top of that you don't need that function as it does nothing useful.

```
bullet[i] = bullet:remove()
bullet[i] = nil
```

The first line is non necessary. You don't have to assign an emtpy table and then nil. Just assign `nil`.

If you'd just keep the bullets in the array part of the table you wouldn't need your own tablelength function and then subtract 2 btw.
Then you could also use table.remove to remove bullets without creating unexpected gaps in your bullet list.

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand, the ```for``` loop is always starting at 0 when bullet[0] does not always exist, even if bullet[1] does. TYSM! Game Jam is due in 2 days, wish me luck!

Comment: I have a question, is there a way I can shift the tables to the left? Example: ```bullet[0]``` and ```bullet[1]``` exist, and soon ```bullet[0]``` is removed, then move everything from ```bullet[1]``` to the new empty ```bullet[0]``` and, theoretically ```bullet[2]``` into ```bullet[1]``` if it exists, you know what I mean?

Comment: don't start your table at 0, but 1. Then you can use table.remove to achieve that